# Is it possible to install Bonjour Service without the Print Services on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, bonjour, zeroconf, software-bundling

Apple provides [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999) to download and install Bonjour.

After installation, it includes 2 products - the `Bonjour Service` itself and `Bonjour Print Services`.

Is is possible to install only the `Bonjour Service` for Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using that linked package, I opened up BonjourPSSetup.exe in WinRAR and was able to extract Bonjour.msi from it (you could use Bonjour64.msi on 64-bit I guess).

[image: Bonjour setup package in WinRAR]

It's then possible to install from Bonjour.msi - I haven't fully tested it through to completion myself but hopefully that would be a way for you to install the Bonjour Service without the Bonjour Print Services.

Comment: You can also extract it with 7-zip or other free product.

Answer (score 3):

I installed complete package (Bonjour print services for Windows ver 2.2) and then removed only Bonjour Print Service. That removed BPS but left Bonjour service intact.